# GIMP: Reinterpret color channels as HSV

Tags: colors, gimp

Suppose I export a 3-dimensional array as a P6 `.pbm` file, with the implicit assumption that the values are to be interpreted in the HSV colorspace, rather than the RGB colorspace.

When I open the file in GIMP, it assumes that the color channels are RGB. However, that isn't what I want.

Is there any way to make GIMP reinterpret the image data as HSV?

Comment: Can you make a small sample file available?

Answer (score 0):

Is using Gimp a requirement? Could you use ImageMagick instead? In that case, it should be very easy:

```
convert picture.pbm -set colorspace HSL out.png
```

should convert  your picture to what you want. Please, have a look at the exact name of various colorspaces at this page http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#other because there are several colorspaces related to HSV and it looks like ImageMagick use other names; look at the line containing the list HSB,HSL,HSI,OTHA which seems to be what you want.

If on the other hand Gimp is for you a major requirement, you could do it this way (though rather a ugly way):

- open the HSV picture; don't care about how it looks now since Gimp thinks it is RGB;
- convert it into HSV (it's obviously a stupid thing to do, but wait), it should open a new window with three separate channels containing garbage;
- go back to the original window and convert it into RGB (it's obviously a stupid thing to do but anyway...); it should open a new window with three separate channels containing H, S, V though Gimp will assume they are R, G, B;
- close the original file;
- copy, channel by channel, the three pictures from the pseudo RGB picture to the corresponding channels in the pseudo HSV picture; the garbage HSV content will be replaced with the real HSV;
- close the RGB window;
- recombine the HSV channels in the last window

Comment: A Decompose to RGB followed by a Compose as HSV won't do?

Comment: @Michael Schumacher Maybe... It should, but I think remembering having encountered some difficulties with that way (like being forced to recompose as RGB or something like that) but I may be wrong.

Comment: Recompose is a different function - it is supposed to recompose the image exactly as it has been decomposed, without any additional user interaction, and if the original image window is still around, it will even recompose there. It is mostly meant for a "decompose, edit individual components, recompose to see result" workflow.